# Guardar resultados de query en array y recorrerlo en ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

Apartir de los resultados de una query, ¿como puedo colocarlos en un array y recorrer cada valor del array?, ya que necesito el valor de cada registro que devuelve la query por que uso ese valor como parámetro para ejecutar otra query, solo he visto ejemplos donde usan una tabla pero en si, no se como adecuarlo a la Query, estoy usando Oracle.

```
DECLARE
     TYPE INFOPAISES IS TABLE OF PAISES%ROWTYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
     datosPais INFOPAISES;
BEGIN
     datosPais(1).nombre := 'ECUADOR';
     datosPais(1).continente := 'AMERICA';

     datosPais(2).nombre := 'MEXICO';
     datosPais(2).poblacion := 'AMERICA';

     FOR i IN datosPais.FIRST..datosPais.LAST
     LOOP
          dbms_output.put_line('Pais: ' || datosPais(i).nombre || '. Continente: ' || datosPais(i).continente);
     END LOOP;
END;
```

los datos que quiero recorrer son estos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y la query donde obtengo esos datos es:

```
select ARCHIVO_GENERADO, SUM(DIFERENCIA) from TablaA where Folio='E7777' and TIPO = 1 group by ARCHIVO_GENERADO;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar un *cursor implícito*: `for/in select` para recorrer directamente los resultados de la consulta.

Un ejemplo sería:

```
for Archivo in
(select   ARCHIVO_GENERADO
        , SUM(DIFERENCIA) TotalDiferencia
   from TablaA 
  where Folio='E7777' 
    and TIPO = 1 
  group by ARCHIVO_GENERADO
)
loop
  --acá haz lo que quieras con el resultado de cada fila del cursor
  dbms_output.put_line('Archivo: ' || Archivo.ARCHIVO_GENERADO);
  dbms_output.put_line('Total: ' || to_char(Archivo.TotalDiferencia));
end loop;
```